# How do I cURL a file across to a CakePHP controller action?

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, curl

I'm trying to send a file to a CakePHP controller using cURL to be saved.  Something like:

```
$file_path = "/full/path/to/file.wav";
$data = array(
    'contents'  => '@'.$file_path
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/cakeapp/uploads/putItem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to pick up $data on the other side, not in $this->data or in any other way I can think of.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: "Does any other way you can think of" include `$this->params['form']`? Just to be sure.

Comment: $this->params['form'] is currently empty too... I'll keep checking for rookie errors though, it could always be something really stupid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyingly (but perhaps unsurprisingly) it doesn't seem to be a problem in the code above, but in pointing at a page on localhost; I moved the cake app to another location and lo and behold, $this->params['form'] was present and correct.  There could still be a better answer to this question if anyone knows what might be causing cURL to fail in such circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$data = array('data' => 
    array( 'contents'  => '@'.$file_path)
);
```

Let me know if that results in content in the $this->data... It should.

post variable 'data' becomes $this->data in the controller in CakePHP.

Comment: That's a good thought - in practice I'm not getting an array to string conversion error in the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); line?  I'll try following this line of inquiry for a while though...

Answer (score 0):

I advace, istead http://localhost/cakeapp/uploads/putItem use:

```
$url = Router::url(
    array(
        'controller' => 'controller',
        'action'     => 'action',
        param_if_needed1,
        param_if_needed2
    ),
    true //absolute, false ( default ) - relative
);
```

also try `"@/full/path/to/file.wav"` without concatenation

Check with [http-sniffer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/?src=search) transferred parameters with 'manual' submit. 
Chek debug level in CakePHP and error-reporting in php.ini